Why Does First Run of Timeshift take forever
I installed timeshift via "sudo apt install timeshift" (Ubuntu 22 because RDP doesn't facilitate screen sharing of the logged on user in 24).  I used pretty much the defaults when setting up for the first snapshot to a Samsung T7 Shield externally mounted on USB.
The initial scan took quite a while but finally completed.  I asked for daily backups with 5 days retention.
The next day no backups had taken place, so I initiated one via CLI.  This backup has been running about 20 hours and the estimated elapsed time to completion keeps incrementing, not decrementing.  Below is the screen shot from command.  What's taking so long?
Image I tried to load shows:
root@xyz:-# timeshift --check

/dev/sdd5 is mounted at: /run/timeshift/backup, options: rw,relatime,stripe=8191

Daily snapshots are enabled
Last daily snapshot not found
------------------------------------------------------------
Creating new snapshot...(RSYNC)
Saving to device: /dev/sdd5, mounted at path: /run/timeshift/backup
Synching files with RSYNC...
  6.32% complete (349:49:14 remaining)


Its helpful if you're clear & specific with details; there is no Ubuntu 22, so do you mean this is a Ubuntu Core 22 headless install?  (there is no apt in Ubuntu Core; only 22.04 or a standard release uses deb packages)

Ubuntu 22.04.5 is the release
